# customizing the redis cache data directory

Tags: redis

I have installed the redis in centos stream 8,

my requirement was to change default directory to custom directory default directory is "/var/lib/redis" i have changed it to "/root/data" and changed the directory owner/group to redis and permission to 755

changed the custom data directory path in "/etc/redis.conf" file and restarted the redis service..

it is getting failed and checked in the "/var/log/redis/redis.log" file the error is Can't chdir to '/root/data': Permission denied

Can anyone help me out on this issue.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: While `redis` user has rights in `/root/data`, probably it has no rights in `/root`. So it can not chdir to `/root/data`.

Comment: Yes, So what can be the solution

Comment: You should use some path where redis user is able to navigate and write

Comment: Is it possible to change the default data directory of redis to custom data directory , if its possible please let me know the steps ,since  I have been struggling with this issue from many days.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This permission denied issue has nothing to do with file/dir perms as one should think, but rather with a safety measure that Redis implements at service level.

### Steps to change the DB on Ubuntu 22

We will be changing the Db from the standard /var/lib/redis path to new /dirA/dirB path

1. mkdir -p /dirA/dirB
2. sudo systemctl stop redis.service
3. sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf and edit the line reading: dir /var/lib/redis to read dir /dirA/dirB. Save file and exit
4. sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/redis.service. Add a new line reading ReadWritePaths=-/dirA/dirB. Save file and exit
5. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
6. sudo systemctl start redis.service

Ready to go with a new DB!

**WARNING**

This, on my test machine, caused the stopjobs to stuck so reboots took a lot of time. To solve it you can set TimeoutStopSec to a number different from 0 on /etc/systemd/system/redis.service

5s or 10s are rather used values.